# How to query/get data under one node android firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my database structure looks like:

```
myDatabasename
name1:{
    UserID: { 
       uniqueId: {
         Data1: ""
         Data1: ""
    }

    UserID: { 
       uniqueId: {
         Data1: ""
         Data1: ""
    }
}
name2:{
    UserID: { 
       uniqueId: {
         Data1: ""
         Data1: ""
    }

    UserID: { 
       uniqueId: {
         Data1: ""
         Data1: ""
    }
```

I would like to retrieve data from just name1 part of the node but I am not sure how I can do this: Previously I did not have name1 and name2, so I was able to retrieve data like this; which worked fine.

```
 for (DataSnapshot ds1: ds.getChildren()) {
        DATA data= ds1.getValue(DATA.class);
        datas.add(data);
    }
```

I am new to firebase, so I am not sure how I can do this, I tried playing around, but it underlines `ds.getChildren("name1") in red`

```
for (DataSnapshot ds1: ds.getChildren("name1")) {
            DATA data= ds1.getValue(DATA.class);
            datas.add(data);
        }

DATA data = ds1.equals("name1").getValue(DATA.class); // I tried this but it also throws red line under getValue;
```

==== EDIT

Sorry for the confusion before the structure above, my structure looked like and I was able to read this by using the code above.

```
UserID: { 
  uniqueId: {
     Data1: ""
     Data1: ""
   }
  uniqueId: {
     Data2: ""
     Data2: ""
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all children of `name1` using:

```
for(DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    // your codes
}
```

But you should point the listener to `name1` as reference.

```
databaseReference.child("name1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Or, you also can do this:

```
for(DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.child("name1").getChildren()){
    // your codes
}
```

And create a listener:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

You can use other listener methods.

Comment: Hi, where do I need to create the listener/ how can I create one.

Comment: inside onCreate method is OK.

Comment: @SumOne you said you were able to retrieve "name1" when there was no "name2". So, you can use the listener you've made. Or if you really need help, you can post your code in MainActivity and Data class. I'll help

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, before I did not have the name1 and name2 fields. I have updated my question with the previous structure I had.

Comment: After playing around with your code, the first approach worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I have another question, it was like this before as well. For some reason my app is only reading the first element/data from first nod and not from the rest. For example If i have 2 userIDs it only reas data from the first userId. do you know how it can be fixed?

Comment: Should I try this inside the listener or the for each loop?

Comment: That was a stupid question, sorry ^ :) I tried the tag thing and its displaying all data on the console but in the recyclerview it only shows from one userID..

Comment: sorry i am a little bit confused with the problem you faced. Try to debug using `Log.d("TAG", ds1.toString());`. You can try it inside the for loop.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it prints all data from both users in the console but only for the first user in the application

Comment: then you can post another question regarding that problem

Comment: Sure, no problem. What code / how much code should I provide in the question?

Comment: the codes where you fetch Firebase database and populate it in a list of your model class